# How to export data from a database to a json file?

Tags: json, postgresql

In my haskell application  I'm using a database, for now it's Postgresql, but in the future it might also be MySql or Sqlite3. I'm looking for a way to export data from my database to a json file via my application, that is, without using the capabilities of a database. How can I do that, is there a relatively easy way? I can do that in a straightforward way, of course, if there're no other options. Your suggestions?

Comment: you can `copy( select to_json` for every table